# Android hangs on installing app.apk when firebase_messaging dependency is added

Tags: android, firebase, intellij-idea, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use firebase messaging (among other firebase functionalities) in my flutter app. I've already had a lot of trouble installing firestore for android (the firebase tutorial worked fine for ios) but now when I try to add the messaging dependency I'm getting a new (and even more opaque) error: When I run the android simulator after calling `flutter get packages`, I get the following message:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
```

and then the program just hangs. The app does not finish building, I can't open it on the simulation device, and the program doesn't seem to be making any progress (I've tried leaving it for 15 minutes or so, but to no avail). This does not happen when I exclude the `firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6` dependency.

Here is the dependency section of my .yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.6
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.6 //this is the problematic line
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

and here is some information about my setup:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X, locale en-US)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.1.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Finally, this is my version of google services (in android/build.gradle)

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1"
    }
```

Does anyone know why this hang would be happening and how to resolve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in `android\build.gradle` make sure you have:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

in `gradle-wrapper.properties` make sure you have:
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip`

lastly: run `flutter upgrade`

just to be sure run also `flutter clean`